# Dropdowns not rendered when override object.cshtml MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My actual problem was mentioned here.
[Hide property of model in dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849895/hide-property-of-model-in-dynamic-view)

To solve the problem, I have overrided object.cshtml as mentioned in the answer.

However, when I did this, the dropdowns that I am rendering using UIHints are not working.
In place of dropdown, just False, False False (the no.of Falses are equal to number of list items I have in my viewdata) are displayed.

I am not sure what is happening here, can somebody advise what is going on?

in my controller:

```
        ViewData["PartyRoleTypeId"] = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)PartyRoleTypeRepo.All()
          .ToList()
          .Select(p => new SelectListItem { Value = p.PartyRoleTypeId.ToString(), Text = p.Caption, Selected = p.PartyRoleTypeId == obj.PartyRoleTypeId });

        ViewData["PartyId"] = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)PartyRepo.All()
          .ToList()
          .Select(p => new SelectListItem { Value = p.PartyId.ToString(), Text = p.Organization.Caption, Selected = p.PartyId == obj.PartyId });
```

My dropdown edit template in shared/editortemplates/DropDownList.cshtml

```
@{
var fieldName = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
 }
 @Html.DropDownList("",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData[fieldName], "Choose..." ,  new { @class ="combo"})
```

object.cshtml

```
@functions
{
bool ShouldShow (ModelMetadata metadata)
{
    return metadata.ShowForEdit
        && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
        && !metadata.IsComplexType
        && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
}
}

@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1)
{
if (Model == null)
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText
}
else
{
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
}
}
else
{
//ViewData.Clear();

foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm)))
{
    if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
    {
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
    }
    else if (prop.DisplayName == "Id")
    {
        <div></div>   
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Label(prop.PropertyName).ToHtmlString()))
    {
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)</div>
    }
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "")</div>
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem with keeping my dropdown values in ViewData or ViewBag.
When I use these, for prartyroletypeid it is not recognizing UIHint dropdownlist.cshtml. It is still referring to object.cshtml. 
Instead I kept the dropdown data in TempData and everything is working fine.

But not sure, if I can use TempData in this context.

Any ideas???